# How to add fade effect to .hide() and .show() without both showing

Tags: jquery

I wrote sample code to make 2 tabs new and trend

```
$(function() {
$("#t1").click(function() {
    $("#t2").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#newTrend").hide();
    $("#newContent").show();
});
$("#t2").click(function() {
    $("#t1").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#newContent").hide();
    $("#newTrend").show();
});
});
```

The code working great but I want to add effect like fade when the tabs changing

Here my code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ta3Q4/

And when I use .fadeOut() and .fadeIn() instead of .hide() and .show()

New tab and trend tab both shown at the same time see here http://jsfiddle.net/Ta3Q4/1/ what I mean

**So how to make fade in and fade out without 2 tabs shown at the same time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fadeOut` callback:

```
$(function() {
    $("#t1").click(function() {

        $("#t2").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#newTrend").fadeOut(400, function() {            
            $("#newContent").fadeIn(400);
        });

    });
    $("#t2").click(function() {

        $("#t1").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#newContent").fadeOut(400, function() {           
            $("#newTrend").fadeIn(400);
        });     
    });
});
```

This way you don't fade in the new element until the old element has faded out completely.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta3Q4/7/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $("#t1").click(function() {
        $("#t2").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#newTrend").fadeOut('slow',function() {
            $("#newContent").fadeIn();
                });
    });
    $("#t2").click(function() {
        $("#t1").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#newContent").fadeOut('slow',function() {
            $("#newTrend").fadeIn();
                });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `fadeIn()` as a callback to `fadeOut`.

```
$("#newContent").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#newTrend").fadeIn();   
});

$("#newTrend").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#newContent").fadeIn();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ta3Q4/6/